# LZMADecompressor not working correctly

Tags: python-3.x, lzma

I am trying to use `lzma` to compress and decompress some data in memory. I know that the following approach works:

```
import lzma

s = 'Lorem ipsum dolor'

bytes_in = s.encode('utf-8')

print(s)
print(bytes_in)

# Compress
bytes_out = lzma.compress(data=bytes_in, format=lzma.FORMAT_XZ)
print(bytes_out)

# Decompress
bytes_decomp = lzma.decompress(data=bytes_out, format=lzma.FORMAT_XZ)

print(bytes_decomp)
```

The output is:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor
b'Lorem ipsum dolor'
b'\xfd7zXZ\x00\x00\x04\xe6\xd6\xb4F\x02\x00!\x01\x16\x00\x00\x00t/\xe5\xa3\x01\x00\x10Lorem ipsum dolor\x00\x00\x00\x00\xddq\x8e\x1d\x82\xc8\xef\xad\x00\x01)\x112\np\x0e\x1f\xb6\xf3}\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04YZ'
b'Lorem ipsum dolor'
```

---

However, I notice that using `lzma.LZMACompressor` gives different results. With the following code:

```
import lzma

s = 'Lorem ipsum dolor'

bytes_in = s.encode('utf-8')

print(s)
print(bytes_in)

# Compress    
lzc = lzma.LZMACompressor(format=lzma.FORMAT_XZ)
lzc.compress(bytes_in)
bytes_out = lzc.flush()
print(bytes_out)

# Decompress
bytes_decomp = lzma.decompress(data=bytes_out, format=lzma.FORMAT_XZ)

print(bytes_decomp)
```

I get this output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor
b'Lorem ipsum dolor'
b'\x01\x00\x10Lorem ipsum dolor\x00\x00\x00\x00\xddq\x8e\x1d\x82\xc8\xef\xad\x00\x01)\x112\np\x0e\x1f\xb6\xf3}\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04YZ'
```

And then the program fails on line 18 with `_lzma.LZMAError: Input format not supported by decoder`.

---

I have 3 questions here:

1. How come the output for `lzma.compress` is so much longer than `lzma.LZMACompressor.compress` even though it seemingly does the same thing?
2. In the second example, why does the decompressor complain about invalid format?
3. How can I get the second example to decompress correctly?

Answer (score 0):

On your second example you're dropping a part of the compressed stream, and `bytes_out` only gets the `flush` part. On the other hand, that works:

```
lzc = lzma.LZMACompressor(format=lzma.FORMAT_XZ)
bytes_out = lzc.compress(bytes_in) + lzc.flush()
print(bytes_out)
```

note that the first example is really equivalent since source for `lzma.compress` is:

```
def compress(data, format=FORMAT_XZ, check=-1, preset=None, filters=None):
    """Compress a block of data.

    Refer to LZMACompressor's docstring for a description of the
    optional arguments *format*, *check*, *preset* and *filters*.

    For incremental compression, use an LZMACompressor instead.
    """
    comp = LZMACompressor(format, check, preset, filters)
    return comp.compress(data) + comp.flush()
```